# Need to use Azure Keyvault Secret value as a variable in Ansible

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-keyvault, ansible-2.x

I want to create a user in ansible and while creating user I want to pass the password which I will get from ansible Key Vault.Please let me know how to do it. I have followed Microsoft documentation link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/ansible/key-vault-configure-secrets?tabs=ansible

````
  user: 
    name: username  
    uid: UID
    group: grpname
    shell: /bin/bash
    comment: "test user"
    password: < **Secret Key value from ansible key vault** >```
````

Please help me getting secret key value from azure key vault.

Comment: Can we know what we you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
tasks:
- name: connect AzPowerShell to Azure
  shell: |
    az login --service-principal -u "{{ servicePrincipalId }}" -p "{{ servicePrincipalPassword }}" --tenant "{{ tenantId }}"
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/bash
- name: Run a pwsh command
  shell: az keyvault secret show --name "{{ vaultSecretName }}" --vault-name "{{ vaultName }}" --query value -o tsv
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/bash
  register: result
- debug:
    msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

I took this example from https://github.com/CloudSkills/using-ansible-with-azure/blob/master/5-lookup-azure-key-vault-secrets-with-ansible/lookup-azure-key-vault-secrets-with-ansible.md

I recommend you to read through the whole git repo - it's a very good explanation of ansible and azure workflow.